# angular bootstrap datepicker default custom class, highlight current date

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I need to update all my datepickers so they display current day highlighted. I found code `custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"` , but do i really need to copy-paste this to EVERY datepicker directive? Is there a way to set it in config so it affect all datepickers already existing on a page?

I tried `uibDatepickerPopupConfig.customClass = function(data){return "class"}` but its not working.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution without modifying source code.
First we need to add new template to $templateCache and then we need to extend datepicker directive scope with new function for returning custom class.

```
    $templateCache.put("uib/template/datepicker/day.html",
           "<table role=\"grid\" aria-labelledby=\"{{::uniqueId}}-title\" aria-activedescendant=\"{{activeDateId}}\">\n" +
           "  <thead>\n" +
           "    <tr>\n" +
           "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left uib-left\" ng-click=\"move(-1)\" tabindex=\"-1\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\"></i><span class=\"sr-only\">previous</span></button></th>\n" +
           "      <th colspan=\"{{::5 + showWeeks}}\"><button id=\"{{::uniqueId}}-title\" role=\"heading\" aria-live=\"assertive\" aria-atomic=\"true\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm uib-title\" ng-click=\"toggleMode()\" ng-disabled=\"datepickerMode === maxMode\" tabindex=\"-1\"><strong>{{title}}</strong></button></th>\n" +
           "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right uib-right\" ng-click=\"move(1)\" tabindex=\"-1\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></i><span class=\"sr-only\">next</span></button></th>\n" +
           "    </tr>\n" +
           "    <tr>\n" +
           "      <th ng-if=\"showWeeks\" class=\"text-center\"></th>\n" +
           "      <th ng-repeat=\"label in ::labels track by $index\" class=\"text-center\"><small aria-label=\"{{::label.full}}\">{{::label.abbr}}</small></th>\n" +
           "    </tr>\n" +
           "  </thead>\n" +
           "  <tbody>\n" +
           "    <tr class=\"uib-weeks\" ng-repeat=\"row in rows track by $index\" role=\"row\">\n" +
           "      <td ng-if=\"showWeeks\" class=\"text-center h6\"><em>{{ weekNumbers[$index] }}</em></td>\n" +
           "      <td ng-repeat=\"dt in row\" class=\"uib-day text-center\" role=\"gridcell\"\n" +
           "        id=\"{{::dt.uid}}\"\n" +
           "        ng-class=\"::dt.customClass\">\n" +
           "        <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm\"\n" +
           "          ng-class=\"highlightCurrentDate(dt)\"\n" +
           "          uib-is-class=\"\n" +
           "            'btn-info' for selectedDt,\n" +
           "            'active' for activeDt\n" +
           "            on dt\"\n" +
           "          ng-click=\"select(dt.date)\"\n" +
           "          ng-disabled=\"::dt.disabled\"\n" +
           "          tabindex=\"-1\"><span ng-class=\"::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}\">{{::dt.label}}</span></button>\n" +
           "      </td>\n" +
           "    </tr>\n" +
           "  </tbody>\n" +
           "</table>\n" +
           "");
```

You see we addednew line `ng-class=\"highlightCurrentDate(dt)\"\n" +`

And then we extend datepicker scope as i wrote:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.datepicker')
.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('uibDatepickerDirective', function ($delegate, $timeout) {
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        var link = directive.link;

        directive.compile = function () {
            return function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
                link.apply(this, arguments);


                scope.highlightCurrentDate = function (dt) {
                    if (dt.selected) {
                        return "";
                    }
                    var date = dt.date;
                    var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    var currentDay = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

                    if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
                        return 'highlight-current-date';
                    }
                }

        };
        return $delegate;
    });
});
```